# Install Twig 2.0 from source

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to install the Twig template engine. I downloaded the source and copied the `lib/Twig` folder inside my `src/lib/Twig` project folder. But there is no `autoload.php`or `Autoloader.php` inside this folder so I can't simply run

```
require_once 'src/lib/Twig/autoload.php';
```

How can I install it ? Where do I find the `autoload.php` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Twig is supposed to be installed with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), you can find the composer.json in the repository. That would also generate the neccessary loader.

If you really want to install it yourself, set up your psr-0 compatible autolader like [the composer.json](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2.x/composer.json#L37) tells you. Also pay attention to the requirements block, install those too and set up their autoloading mechanism.

Composer really eases installing libraries with all their dependencies, I highly recommend getting familiar with it.